# Overriding PHP extension

Tags: php, apache, ldap, php-extension

I tweaked PHP ldap extension a bit, and now I want to override the default ldap extension in php. I changed the name of my extension to ldap2, added `extension=ldap2.so` to `php.ini`. I do so, because dont want loose the changes of my tweaks after `apt-get update`. Whould PHP call my function `ldap_bind()` instead of `ldap_bind()` from default ldap extension? Because I can't disable it, but most of function names left the same.

Comment: If you write your own extension, you have to go the complete route till the end and also create new function names.

Comment: Just uninstall the original ldap extension. That way it won't be overwritten on update..